# AVAssetReaderTrackOutput hangs on copyNextSampleBuffer

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I've hit the issue with `AVAssetWritter`. Sometimes happens that my video writing session just hangs. After inspecting threads which are currently running on my device, I found that whole video processing is waiting for `copyNextSampleBuffer` to return. I have no idea what can cause this issue. Does anyone have successfully overcome that problem?

Below is thread dump captured from instruments. It ends on `mach_msg_trap`.
[image: Thread stack]

#### Video processing loop

```
while ([self.assetWriterVideoInput isReadyForMoreMediaData] && !(*completedOrFailed) && !self.cancelled)
    {
        @autoreleasepool {
            
            
            CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer = [self.assetReaderVideoOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];
            
                        
            
            CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
            CVPixelBufferRef croppedBuffer = NULL;
            NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                     [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey,
                                     [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey, nil];
            CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, self.outputSize.width, self.outputSize.height, CVPixelBufferGetPixelFormatType(pixelBuffer), (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) options, &croppedBuffer);
            CIImage *img = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer];
            
            // img processing
           
            
            [self.context render:img toCVPixelBuffer:croppedBuffer];
            
            
            if (sampleBuffer != NULL)
            {
                
                BOOL success = [self.avPixelAdaptor appendPixelBuffer:croppedBuffer withPresentationTime:sampleTime];
                
                CFRelease(sampleBuffer);
                sampleBuffer = NULL;
                *completedOrFailed = !success;
            }
            else
            {
                *completedOrFailed = YES;
            }
            CVPixelBufferRelease(croppedBuffer);
        }
    }
}
```

### Update

Source asset for asset reader is `AVMutableComposition` which consists of several `AVURLAsset`'s which are pointing to photo library (i.e. url = "assets-library://asset/asset.MOV?id=4CA9A2C6-F2D4-4FDF-AAEC-6335B9BD840A&ext=MOV"). From each source asset is taken 2 seconds which begin after 0.6s of source asset. If all source assets starts from 0, then video processing never hangs.

### Summary

The main question is: What are the conditions which can cause `copyNextSampleBuffer` to wait for exit forever. Documentation doesn't mention such situation.

Comment: do you have a small project on github that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Nope, I don't have such project :(

Comment: it would be great if you could make one

Comment: Did you ever make progress here? I have the same issue, just reading the sample buffers to display in an AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer (no writing)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that you marked the input as finished and ended the session in your code like below. Did you call these finalizers?

```
//Finish the session:
[writerInput markAsFinished];
[videoWriter endSessionAtSourceTime:totalDuration];

[videoWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:^{

// Handle videoWriter.status here

}];
```

Answer (score 0):

This bug can also appear on `AVPlayer` and `AVAssetExportSession` too. My solution can be used for `AVPlayerItem` or `AVAssetExportSession`.

Took me a while to understand what's going on. Im'still not 100% sure about it, but that's what i figured out:

The problem is source and target time mapping of your videos. I can guess if you check `videoTrack.segments` (first one, for example) `segment.timeMapping.source.start` will not be equal to `segment.timeMapping.target.start`. By default, internally, `AVVideoComposition` will inherit `sourceTrackIDForFrameTiming` from your original assets in composition, and everything about timing, framerate, etc and this will cause the bug. If you will not set the videoComposition for exporting, it will do the same thing. I can guess that some internal logic of asset reader will broke the time calculation for this specific case.

So for the fix, you can set `sourceTrackIDForFrameTiming` for `AVVideoComposition`.

As `assetReaderVideoOutput` you should use `AVAssetReaderVideoCompositionOutput` with `videoComposition` assigned to it.

You can create videoComposition like this, for example:

```
    let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition(propertiesOf: mutableComposition)

    //MARK: - The most important thing
    videoComposition.sourceTrackIDForFrameTiming = kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid

    videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 30)
    videoComposition.renderScale  = 1.0
    videoComposition.renderSize = CGSize(width: 720.0, height: 1280.0)
    
    let layerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: compositionVideoTrack)
    
    let mainInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
    mainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: .zero, duration: composition.duration)
    mainInstruction.layerInstructions = [layerInstruction]
    
    videoComposition.instructions = [mainInstruction]
```

Change the hardcoded values for your needs here. You can also use `let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()` initializer without setting sourceTrackIDForFrameTiming, in my tests, this also worked. Assign the `videoComposition` to the `assetReaderVideoOutput`. And export.

That's it!